# Using str.format() in Python Cassandra Driver?

Tags: python, cassandra, string-formatting

I had a Python cassandra-driver question...

On the website, it shows us how to make insert queries...

http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html

They recommend doing something like...

```
session.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO users (name, credits, user_id)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    """,
    ("John O'Reilly", 42, uuid.uuid1())
)
```

Where we make use of the built in `execute(...)` method.

However, I'm very comfortable with the oh-so-powerful str.format()... so is it wrong to just do...

```
session.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO users (name, credits, user_id)
    VALUES ({}, {}, {})
    """.format("John O'Reilly", 42, uuid.uuid1())
)
```

Or is there some benefit to following the instructions on the website?